# Log4Net: Rolling File appender, custom file name

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I want my logfile to have the following format:

> yyyy-mm-dd-[area]{-[optional tag]}.log

so that I end up with something like 2016-08-23-Area-PerformanceTesting.log, where Area = [area] and PerformanceTesting = the [optional tag].

I am having trouble adding the 'area' string variable *after* the date, as well as with the optional tag variable.

The resulting filename turns out to be this, which is wrong:

> {yyyy-MM-dd(tt)}.Name.2016-08-23(PM).log

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <param name="File" value="C:\Logs\%date{yyyy-MM-dd(tt)}.Name.log" />

      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Composite" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="1000" />
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="25MB" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
      <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd(tt)" />
      <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.fff} %message%newline" />
      </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter is incorrect, it needs to have "type="log4net.Util.PatternString"" added to the File tag:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"  value="Test1.%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}xxxxxxxx.log" />
```